# Confusing about raid-z and new disk added

Tags: zfs

During experiments with raid-z on Solaris-CBE I obtain this

I create a raid-z pool

```
zpool create pool1 raidz c4t3d0 c4t5d0 c4t4d0
```

Then I want to add a disk

```
zpool add pool1 c5t0d0
```

return error (pool1 is raid-z, vdev is disk, use -f..)

I use -f (force)

```
zpool add -f pool1  c5t0d0
```

It works!

```
zpool status pool1
  pool: pool1
    ID: 8550511546950241199
 state: ONLINE


        NAME        STATE      READ WRITE CKSUM
        pool1       ONLINE        0     0     0
          raidz1-0  ONLINE        0     0     0
            c4t3d0  ONLINE        0     0     0
            c4t5d0  ONLINE        0     0     0
            c4t4d0  ONLINE        0     0     0
          c5t0d0    ONLINE        0     0     0
```

My question is: what kind of configuration is this? c5t0d0 is a sub-mirror of pool1 or what else?

Comment: Is there also a follow-up question hanging in the air? "How should I have added this disk to the `raidz1-0` array?"

Comment: and the answer to that implied follow-up question is "you can't add a single drive to a pool without destroying redundancy...it just makes what is effectively a RAID-0 with your raidz vdev and the single disk vdev".  And you can't just add a drive to a raid-z vdev - if you need to do that, the only way is to backup everything on the pool (e.g. with `zfs snapshot` and `zfs send` to either another pool with `zfs receive`, or to a file on another disk or another system via ssh) then destroy the pool and re-create it with all four drives in raidz1-0, then restore your data.

Comment: alternatively, you could add three more drives as a second raidz vdev in the pool.  or use `zpool replace` to individually replace each drive in the vdev with larger drives (but backup, destroy, re-create and restore is typically **much** faster).

Comment: Yes I know, I wrote it in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer by myself. Is a pool (pool1) which contain 2 submirror (raidz 1-0 first, the lonely disk is the second ).
The pool is correct with syntax but wrong for redundancy. The lonely disk (c5t0d0) is the wrong thing because there is no redundancy
If we need more space is possible to add another raidz mirror or raid1.
Something like this

```
zpool add pool1 raidz c5t0d0 c5t1d0 c5t2d0
```

The data is written to all disk even with a single disk (but is wrong for redundancy), the proof are the 4 disk images (the Solaris 11 cbe is a vm on Linux host) growing

```
du -shc .local/share/libvirt/images/vol*
2,1G    .local/share/libvirt/images/vol1.img
2,1G    .local/share/libvirt/images/vol2.img
2,1G    .local/share/libvirt/images/vol3.img
2,1G    .local/share/libvirt/images/vol4.img
```

after sometime writing data...

```
du -shc .local/share/libvirt/images/vol*
2,7G    .local/share/libvirt/images/vol1.img
2,7G    .local/share/libvirt/images/vol2.img
2,7G    .local/share/libvirt/images/vol3.img
2,7G    .local/share/libvirt/images/vol4.img
11G total
```

after 10 minutes...

```
du -shc .local/share/libvirt/images/vol*
8,5G    .local/share/libvirt/images/vol1.img
8,5G    .local/share/libvirt/images/vol2.img
8,5G    .local/share/libvirt/images/vol3.img
8,5G    .local/share/libvirt/images/vol4.img
```

Another proof, removing the non-redundant submirror, the array rebuild

```
NAME                        STATE      READ WRITE CKSUM
pool1                       ONLINE        0     0     0
  raidz1-0                  ONLINE        0     0     0
    c4t3d0                  ONLINE        0     0     0
    c4t5d0                  ONLINE        0     0     0
    c4t4d0                  ONLINE        0     0     0
  c5t0d0                    REMOVING      0     0     0
  $VDEV-1151C5D8F59CFF79    REMOVING      0     0     0
```